# Why does macos base64 encode give a different result than btoa in browser

Tags: macos, base64

I'm assuming there's an extra character in there, but I don't understand how I could do this better.

Encoding the letter "a" should result in a code:
`YQ==` as per:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

On mac, I can't get it to output this result despite all the variations I could try:

`openssl base64 -e <<<a` yields `YQo=`

Running:

`openssl base64 -e <<<a|base64 -d|hexdump -C`

Reveals

```
00000000  61 0a                                             |a.|
00000002
```

This is different to:

`echo "YQ=="|base64 -d|hexdump -C`

```
00000000  61                                                |a|
00000001
```

Is there no solution available from console to properly encode? What do I need to do differently?

Comment: `<<<a` is adding a newline to the "a" before sending it to `openssh`, and `openssl` is faithfully encoding both the "a" and the newline. `echo a` would do the same thing. Try `printf '%s' a | openssl base64`

Comment: Also: `echo -n a` to avoid the newline. Theres also no need for `openssl` here. macos has `base64` as a command on its own. `echo -n a | base64` ==> `YQ==`

Comment: Tested it and it works.  I figured there's a new line or something on the end... good to know

Comment: @RobNapier Some versions of `echo` (including the bash builtin in at least one version of macOS) will print "-n" as part of their output, and then  go ahead and print a newline at the end as well. If you want it to work reliably, use `printf` instead.